# Quarkus + Kafka Intercept incoming messages and read headers

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Is there any way to create a Interceptor for a INCOMING message from Kafka, using the smallrye connector in quarkus ? I need this to read the headers and switch Tenants for persisting data.

In spring we can create a consumer interceptor and register it in the app.

For quarkus i see there is a OUTGOING interceptor, but none for a incoming kafka message.

Comment: Would a Kafka interceptor work for you? https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerInterceptor.html

Comment: Smallrye can accept any Kafka client config, so what difficulty are you having with adding Kafka native interceptors?